# Jackson POJO mapping

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to  map the following json via jackson to a pojo. I have the first part working (up until section). However, the second part I'm not sure how I can map "section1" to perhaps a contained pojo or best practice here?

json received via rest call:

```
{
   "val1":100,
   "val2":2.75,
   "junk":[
      {
         "junk1":36,
         "junk2":78
      },
      {
         "junk1":36,
         "junk2":78
      }
   ],
   "section1":{     // <- There will be another section2, section3,...
      "val1":100,
      "val2":2.75,
      "junk1":[
         {
            "junk1":36,
            "junk2":78
         },
         {
            "junk1":36,
            "junk2":78
         }
      ],
      "junk2":[
         {
            "junk1":36,
            "junk2":78
         },
         {
            "junk1":36,
            "junk2":78
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Pojo:

```
public class view
{
    private int val1;
    private float val2;
    private List<Map<String, String> > junk; //<-Ok as I just pass to another class

        // How to store "section" ... and want to keep junk1, junk2 same
        // placeholder like I have for junk in main section above.


}
```

Comment: your JSON will not result into a gud object... do u have a limit on section numbers or junk numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 'section' another class and also 'junk' if the contents of each section (and each piece of junk) has the same structure internally.

```
public class view
{
    private int val1;
    private float val2;
    private List<Junk> junk; //<-Ok as I just pass to another class
    private Section section1;
    private Section section2;
    ... etc ...
}

public class Section {
   private int val1;
    private float val2;
    private List<Junk> junk; //<-Ok as I just pass to another class
}

public class Junk {
   private String junk1;
   private Strign junk2;
}
```

I'm assuming the structure you showed as opposed to an array of sections.

Plus a map isn't a good place to store two random strings. But Jackson will allow it. The only exception is if the names of the fields will vary from 'junk1' and 'junk2'. Otherwise just use a class with two strings in it.

Comment: Ok, cool! I had tried mapping with an aggregate class but it wasn't working. So, I was unsure how jackson mapped contained classes. This is what I was looking for...I'll give it a shot! Thx.

Comment: Nice. The reason for the map is there will be multiple junk1, junk2, junkx within each junk section. The reason I don't store it is because I don't care about those values as I just pass along the junk json altogether and the contents.  I didn't make that clear in my original post.

Comment: Ok. Then ignore my Junk class.

Comment: Either way just tested it. Worked as advertised. Awesome! Thanks Lee Meador! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can indicate that "junk" should be ignored. There are couple of ways to do it; one is to do:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"junk"})
public class MyClass { ... }
```

this has the benefit of not requiring memory to store matching data; and it can speed up parsing a bit (not a ton, but some; parser still needs to decode JSON to skip it etc).

Comment: Very cool! I have a use case where I'm building out a json payload for testing and only half of it is being utilized is really being mapped. The other half comes in blank so this will work perfectly in the junk case and my other half json payload use case.  Thx!